# grouping of taskbar items (by project)

Tags: windows, window-manager

Typically I have about 20 windows (half of them browser windows) and I need some way to visually organize the Windows Taskbar items, perhaps group them by project.

I am typically working on about 5 projects on any given day.

Any tools or methods to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing to what you are looking for, in my limited experience, are so-called jumplist customizers; such an example is [Jumplist Extender](https://code.google.com/p/jumplist-extender/).

Perhaps a little bit more known is [Jumplist-Launcher](http://en.www.ali.dj/jumplist-launcher/); here is a tutorial on how to use it: [tutorial](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-create-your-own-custom-jump-list). I'd start with this one.

Features:

- no installation necessary
- jumplists may have up to 60 programs or files
- the jumplist entries can be grouped (by a separator)
- you can have multiple Jumplist-Launcher-Icons (with different files/programs)
- files can be dragged into the Jumplist-Launcher from Windows-Explorer

...and others.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of virtual desktops and activities in Kubuntu to organize applications by project. [Dexpot](http://www.dexpot.de/index.php?lang=en) offers a similar way to do that on Windows. This way, you can allocate a different virtual desktop for each project with the ability to easily navigate among them.

[image]

Features:

- Up to 20 virtual desktops
- Desktop/Fullscreen preview with drag and drop
- Window catalog to preview all windows

[image]
[image]

<sup>([pictures source](http://www.dexpot.de/index.php?id=features))</sup>